# Эфект на клик jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Ума не приложу как сделать банальную вещь. Есть список. При клике на иконку, добавляется класс active и список раскрывается, при еще одном клике, сворачивается. Нужно сделать так что бы при клике на все остальное кроме этого же списка, список сворачивался.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".active").length == 0) {
    $(".active").сворачивается();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно

```js
jQuery('.list span').click(function(){
  if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
    jQuery('.list span').removeClass('is-active').siblings('ul').slideUp(200);
    jQuery(this).addClass('is-active').siblings('ul').slideDown(200);
  } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('is-active')){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('is-active').siblings('ul').slideUp(200);
  }
})
```

```css
.list ul{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
<span>LOL</span>
<ul>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
<span>LOL</span>
<ul>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
<span>LOL</span>
<ul>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
<li>SomeString</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "при клике на все остальное ... список сворачивался"